# How can I customize code formatting in PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

Is it possible to do arbitrary code formatting in PyCharm? I am trying to create separate lines for each parameter with a comma after the last parameter. E.g.

```py
def f(x, y):
    pass
```

to

```py
def f(
    x,
    y,
):
    pass
```

I am also interested in a more general solution. The closest I found is [EditorConfig](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7294-editorconfig), but that is mostly for code spacing rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't achievable at the moment. There are various feature requests about code formatting (like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22986), but feel free to submit another one for your needs.